# Flexslider Adding Huge White Space Below Slider

Tags: flexslider, removing-whitespace

There is a large amount of white space below my flexslider and I do not know how to remove. I have played with the CSS quite  bit and nothing seems to work, without breaking the "responsive" behavior. Any help is greatly aprpeciated.

Regards...

Site can be viewed here, all code in located in the head tag:
http://destinjustlisted.com/new/

Answer (score 0):

Your div which contains the slideshow items must have the class "flexslider." Various things are setup for that class in flexslider.css, which is part of the download. One of the CSS properties it has is "margin." You'll see three values there. It looks like this:

```
margin: 0 0 60px;
```

I don't know if you're familiar with this property format, but it's common in CSS when you've got 4 settings, as with margin, border, or padding (all of which have 4 sides). You can have up to four values which represent: top, right, bottom, left (like you're going around a clock dial, starting with 12 o'clock). So, for example:

```
padding: 0 1px 0 2px;
```

would give no padding on the top and bottom, but 1 pixel on the right and 2 pixels on the left.

The flexslider CSS has 60 pixels of margin on the bottom. That leaves room for the navigation buttons if you want a visual representation of where you are in your slideshow or for you to select a specific slide. Unfortunately, if you set the property "controlNav" to "false" when you're setting up the plugin if you don't want to show those "buttons," then you just end up with the big blank area under the control. If you just set that property to this:

```
margin: 0;
```

all your problems will be solved!

Answer (score 0):

If your images are different sizes (heights in particular), the Flexslider container will display as high as the tallest image. This can create the gap that you might see.

If this is the cause, resize your images in advance so they all have the same heights and widths.